# JSON hash key manipulation

Tags: ruby, json

I parse the response:

```
response = JSON.parse(response.body)
p response
```

Output

```
{"PC"=>"PC087849", "COUNT"=>"72421"}
{"PC"=>"PC087302", "COUNT"=>"71546"}
{"PC"=>"PC087255", "COUNT"=>"68420"}
```

Then remap the keys:

```
a = response.map{|s| {label: s[0], value: s[1].to_i} }
puts a
```

Output

```
{:label=>nil, :value=>0}
{:label=>nil, :value=>0}
{:label=>nil, :value=>0}
```

Why are the contents of the Key's nil and zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of `response` are hashes, not arrays. It is incorrect to use integers when addressing items inside of a hash (unless the keys are actual integers)

```
response = [{"PC"=>"PC087849", "COUNT"=>"72421"},
{"PC"=>"PC087302", "COUNT"=>"71546"},
{"PC"=>"PC087255", "COUNT"=>"68420"}]

a = response.map{|s| {label: s['PC'], value: s['COUNT'].to_i} }
puts a
# >> {:label=>"PC087849", :value=>72421}
# >> {:label=>"PC087302", :value=>71546}
# >> {:label=>"PC087255", :value=>68420}
```

`s[0]` will give you `nil` because there's no element by that key. `s[1]` will also give you `nil`, but then you call `#to_i` on it. That will give you `0`.

```
nil.to_i # => 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Each element is hash, not array; Use keys (`PC`, `COUNT`) to get value of the hash.

```
response = [
  {"PC"=>"PC087849", "COUNT"=>"72421"},
  {"PC"=>"PC087302", "COUNT"=>"71546"},
  {"PC"=>"PC087255", "COUNT"=>"68420"},
]
response.map { |s| {label: s['PC'], value: s['COUNT'].to_i } } 
# => [
#   {:label=>"PC087849", :value=>72421},
#   {:label=>"PC087302", :value=>71546},
#   {:label=>"PC087255", :value=>68420}
# ]
```